# How to post a file after record with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i use audio package for recording, i want to post that recording sound file on my backend, but after record sound i only get src="file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A011002-F806-41C2-A213-A78917F04175/tmp/12F2BDBF-48F4-4403-ADEC-EF3CD78F558A.m4a", how to post file from it

```
//stop record 
//
  Future<void> _stop() async {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _recordDuration = 0;

    final path = await _audioRecorder.stop();
    ///path = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A011002-F806-41C2-A213-A78917F04175/tmp/12F2BDBF-48F4-4403-ADEC-EF3CD78F558A.m4a
    if (path != null) {
      widget.onStop(path);
    }
  }


/// i want post file like that
  void convertToText() async {
    try {
      final http = Dio();
      http.options.headers['api-key'] = Constant.apiKey;
      http.options.headers['Content-Type'] = '.${audioPath.split('.').last}';
      final result = (await http.post(Constant.apiLinkVoiceToText, data: File(audioPath)));
      print(result.data.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: my err

flutter: DioError [unknown]: null
Error: Error on line 1, column 4: Invalid media type: expected "/".
  ╷
1 │ m4a
  │    ^
  ╵

Comment: Looks like you have to be a bit more careful about your content type. `m4a` isn't a valid content type, but `audio/m4a` is.